# Node.JS Web scraping with Puppeteer failing with error: 'input[value type="email"' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Basically, i'm trying to log in into this form:

[image]

using this script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const screenshot = 'carwow.png'

const scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://dealers.carwow.co.uk/dealers/sign_in')

    await page.type('input type="email"', 'username')
    await page.type('input type="password"', 'password')
    await page.click('name="commit"')

    await page.waitForNavigation()
    await page.screenshot({ path: screenshot })
    browser.close()
    console.log('See screenshot: ' + screenshot)
};


scrape()
```

However, its failing with an error as such:
Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[value type="email"' is not a valid selector.

Comment: The error is correct, the selector is missing the closing square brace `]`. Try the selector `input[value type="email"]`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not super familiar with puppeteer but it looks like the API you're trying to use, e.g. page.type is documented here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v10.4.0/docs/api.md#pagetypeselector-text-options
and it uses CSS selectors for the first argument to test against.

Specifically an attribute selector on an input, here is a short document from W3 on it:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

You may want to try the selector

```
'input[type="email"]'
```

Answer (score 1):

@Diego is right. You can rewrite your selector paths as below:

`'input[type="email"]'` and `'input[type="password"]'` and `"*[name='commit']"`